# "partial grep" to accelerate grep speed?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

This is what I am thinking: `grep` program tries to pattern-match every pattern occurrence in the line, just like:

```
echo "abc abc abc" | grep abc --color
```

the result is that the three `abc` is all red colored, so grep did a full pattern matching to the line.

But think in this scenario, I have many big files to process, but the words that I am interested is very much likely to occur in the first few words. My job is to find the lines without the words in them. So if the `grep` program can continue to the next line when the words have been found without having to check the rest of the line, it would maybe significantly faster.

Is there a `partial match` option maybe in grep to do this?

like:

```
echo abc abc abc | grep --partial abc --color
```

with only the first abc colored red.

Comment: It's likely that the only reason `grep` checks the entire line is *because* you are using `--color`. I would be surprised if `grep` doesn't already stop after the first match without it, since the line will be part of the output regardless of how many times `abc` matches within the line.

Comment: As @chepner mentioned, consider adding `--color=never` to disable coloring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this nice introduction to grep internals:

http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html

In particular:

> GNU grep AVOIDS BREAKING THE INPUT INTO LINES.  Looking for newlines
>   would slow grep down by a factor of several times, because to find the
>   newlines it would have to look at every byte!
>
> So instead of using line-oriented input, GNU grep reads raw data into
>   a large buffer, searches the buffer using Boyer-Moore, and only when
>   it finds a match does it go and look for the bounding newlines.
>   (Certain command line options like -n disable this optimization.)

So the answer is: No. It is way faster for `grep` to look for the next occurrence of the search string, rather than to look for a new line.

*Edit*: Regarding the speculation in the comments to that `color=never` would do the trick: I had a quick glance at the source code. The variable `color_option` is not used anywhere near the the actual search for the regex or the previous and upcoming newline in case a match has been found.

It might be that one could save a few CPU cycles when searching those line terminators. Possibly a real world difference shows up with pathological long lines and a very short search string.

Answer (score 1):

If your job is to find the lines without the words in them, you can give **sed** a try to delete the lines containing the specific word.

```
sed '/word/d' input_file
```

Sed will probably continue to the next line when the first occurrence is found on the current line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find lines without specific words, you can use grep to do this.

Try `grep -v "abc"` which means do the inverse. In this case, find lines without the string "abc".

If I have a file that looks like this:

```
line one abc
line two abc
line three def
```

Doing `grep -v "abc" file.txt` will return `line three def`.